# auth.getInstance not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I like a form in where I can update the user data, forget all the logic behind that, I just want to write something on the inputText and save it in firebase. The thing is that I get an error that I don't know the cause. I did a lot of logs and it never enters the if statement in where I check if the user exist.

**Code**

```
public class UserSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    EditText usernameTxt;
    EditText ageTxt;
    String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_settings);
        usernameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        ageTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    public void user(View view){
        String username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageTxt.getText().toString());
        Log.d("task21",auth.getCurrentUser().toString());

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Log.d("task","fail2");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("task","fail3");
            userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }
        Log.d("task","fail4");


        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.child("Users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(username);
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
04-12 08:11:30.551 19662-19662/com.android.email E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a that was originally bound here
                                                                   android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a that was originally bound here
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
                                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
                                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
                                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                       at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
                                                                       at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
                                                                       at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
                                                                       at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
                                                                       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-12 08:11:30.562 19662-19717/com.android.email E/EmailServiceProxy: RuntimeException when trying to unbind from service
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a
                                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029)
                                                                          at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1808)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
                                                                          at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:124)
                                                                          at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:111)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)04-12 08:11:30.551 19662-19662/com.android.email E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a that was originally bound here
                                                                   android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a that was originally bound here
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
                                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
                                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
                                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                       at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
                                                                       at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
                                                                       at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
                                                                       at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
                                                                       at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
                                                                       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-12 08:11:30.562 19662-19717/com.android.email E/EmailServiceProxy: RuntimeException when trying to unbind from service
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1ae9859a
                                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029)
                                                                          at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1808)
                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
                                                                          at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:124)
                                                                          at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:111)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i thing this error is not belong to your own application some of your email service is leaked.
Second, this should be like this so it want run an exception :

```
else{
  Log.d("task","fail3");
  userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
  DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
  myRef.child("Users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(username).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: DONE");
            }
        }
    });;
 }
```